# Mystery rubbing or slapping noise while driving

Tags: noise, dodge, caravan

My 2005 Dodge Caravan makes a strange rubbing or slapping noise under the hood that is quite loud and has to do with rotation of the tires or front axle. As you slow down it slows down and vice versa if you speed up. It stops when vehicle stops. It doesn't start doing it until after getting out on road for a few minutes and doesn't do it all the time. I crawled under it hoping to find something maybe wrapped around cv axle or tire, but nothing was vizable. It almost sounds like something hitting against firewall or bottom of hood. It also doesn't interfere with performance of engine or trans...

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your fan belt. It could be coming apart and only making noise when you get up to certain speed